# Query on OData Adapters for Salesforce Connect

Tags: lightning-experience, configuration, lightning-connect

I am trying to find out how and when Salesforce fetch data from external system using oData callout.

I have found two article on that and they are contradicting each other.

1. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ext_data_sync_database.htm&type=5 : As per this article Salesforce only sync metadata when we click on Validate and Sync. "**Syncing creates or overwrites Salesforce external objects that map to the external system’s schema. Syncing doesn’t copy any data into your Salesforce org or write data from your org to the external system**."
2. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.odata_adapter_about.htm&type=5 : As per this article Salesforce performs an OData callout each time You validate or sync an external data source.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't believe those articles are actually contradictory at all. The first says that validating and syncing an external data source is a manual process that needs to be done again if the external data source's schema changes. The second simply states that when using the oData connecter an oData query is constructed in order to do the sync. That isn't saying that it does a sync every time the connector is called, which I agree would be contradictory.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich Thanks for spending time to read my post. I could be wrong but If you see the first image , it says Salesforce performs an oData callout ( Callout is used here to fetch the data from my understanding) each time you validate or Sync and external data source ( which can be done from Setup => External Data source by clicking on the validate & sync button manually ) whereas the second image syncing ( from my understanding it refers to  clicking on the validate & sync button manually from Setup) doesn't copy any data into your Salesforce org ( I have highlighted the lines ).

Comment: You're correct, syncing doesn't copy data from the external system to Salesforce. It does however use the structure returned in the oData query to build the External Object schema. I think the confusion here is that you have one article that is discussing how setting up an External Data Source works in general (the validate and sync article) versus one that talks specifically about how the oData connector is working in every scenario.